# IE 11 clearing local storage is broken

Tags: internet-explorer, local-storage, internet-explorer-11

How do you fix Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17501 when you can't clear localStorage? Essentially, `localStorage.clear()` and `windows.localStorage.clear()` give the error message *"Function expected"* from the developer command line in IE.

If this doesn't work, then I can't effectively debug websites using Visual Studio.

Comment: Do you have a small repro? I'm running these commands across numerous domains in the developer tools and finding that they do not raise the exception you referenced. Also, I'm assuming you meant `window.localStorage` (singular).

Comment: Yes, window.LocalStorage.clear()  What doesn't make sense is that on a different website in IE, it works.

Comment: What is the document mode used on the site where it doesn't work? You can check this by pressing F12 and either looking at the top-right where the Document Mode dropdown is available, or navigating to the Emulation tab. Note also, it's `window.localStorage`; the l is lower-case.

Comment: document mode is Edge, though it doesn't seem to make a difference if I change it.

Comment: Can you give me URLs of sites where it is working, and failing?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio's development webserver, so http://localhost:portnumber, where it doesn't seem to matter what the port number is.  Also, I noticed that if I debug a different website, the localStorage values are the same.

Comment: `localStorage` in IEs work only with `http` or `https` protocols.